Getting a Blank Space in Shopify / flash-list
<View style={{flex:1}}>
     <FlashList
              data={routes.current}
              extraData={language}
              renderItem={renderScene}
              keyExtractor={item => item?.id}
              horizontal
              pagingEnabled
              getItemType={() => { return 2 }}
              onBlankArea={(e)=>{
                console.log('e',e)
              }}
              snapToAlignment="start"
              decelerationRate={'fast'}
              snapToOffsets={snapToOffsetsArray}
              disableIntervalMomentum
              estimatedItemSize={ScreenWidth}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            />
          </View>

I am using this and this list is working well but when I open a keyboard on this and close this keyboard then render items wrapped into Half screen and I try to place text on various places like on top. App.js inside renderItem but giving the same result. Is anybody facing the same issue in this?
Blank area starting console
{"blankArea": 0, "offsetEnd": -411.42857142857144, "offsetStart": 0}
Console after opening and closing keyboard
{"blankArea": -575.2380952380952, "offsetEnd": -575.2380952380952, "offsetStart": -659.047619047619}
